# Is Comet possible with spludo framework easily?

Tags: node.js, comet, long-polling

I'm experimenting with Spludo framework (node.js) now and tries to implement comet using socket.io but was unable to connect those two libs. Does anyone have experience with Spludo and socket.io? is it possible to implement comet (actually, I'm interested in long polling) with Spludo at all?

Comment: You may want to consider expressjs as a solid alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I am maintainer of the spludo framework.

Currently it's not easily possible to integrate spludo framework with socket.io. I was looking into that a while back, but haven't fixed that, yet.

You are able to use long polling on your own, since the request will finish as soon as cb is called. You decide when this happens.

Anyways I will look in a way to integrate socket.io for you and give a handy tutorial on how to do that soon.

Comment: That would be cool. Thank you! will try to implement on my own.